# How to create a link and make the text anchor part of the url with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

From `<h2>title-here</h2>` to `<h2><a href="/search/label/title-here">title-here</h2>`

Only one issue left, to insert the "title-here" after label/ inside href.
So far I got this...

```
$('h2').each(function() {
   var addLink = $(this);
   addLink.wrapInner("<a target='_blank' href='/search/label/"+  +"'</a>");
});
```

Pls help. Thanks guys.

Comment: Okay to answer your own question! Rather than add it to your question, post it below and accept it.

Comment: I just realized we have same answer and did not actually check your solution first.. sorry bout that.. Just got excited..

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution and it works!
I just have to keep on trying :)

```
$('h2').each(function() {
   var addLink = $(this);
   addLink.wrapInner("<a href='/search/label/" + addLink.text() + "'</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, a plain javascript version would be:

```
var hs = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (var i = 0, len = hs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var text = hs[i].innerHTML;
    hs[i].innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="/search/label/' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '">' + text + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to make a link out of your title. You can try this then -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h2').each(function(index) {
       var addLink = $(this);
       var title = addLink.html();
       var link = "<a target=\'_blank\' href=\'/search/label/"+title+"\'>" + title + "</a>";
       addLink.html(link);
    });  
});
```

Here is the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4mm5m20m/

You can modify the code to suit yourself.